# Get Item Child Count in search results

Tags: search-results, display-template

I have a picture library which consist of 2 content types: "Photo Album" and "picture". I also have made a search site to search the albums. I have made a custom item display template which show the link, the title and the author. I need the Item child count as well to show how many pictures there are in each Photo Album. Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: What is the parent content type of "Photo Album"?

Comment: Matthew, photo album is a documentset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The property `ItemChildCount` was mapped to the field `ReplyCount`. Adding that field to the display template fixed the problem.